# C# - Create object without null properties

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and having difficulty with creating an object of a class using serialized json string. I have class defined with some member variable as follows:

```
class someClass{
   someclass(serializedJson) {
      JavascriptSerializer js = new JavascriptSerializer();
      var newObj = (someClass)(js.deserialize(serializedJson, typeof(serializedJson)));

   }
   // class has bunch of private and public member variables eg
   private string this._value;
   public string Price{
     get {
       return _price;
     }
     set {
       _price = somePrice;
     }
   }

}
```

Class is being called in some other file to create an object as:

```
var obj = new someClass(serializedJsonString);
```

`serializedJsonString` looks like:

```
{
  ... : ...,
  ... : ...
  // contains no key value pair for Price that I am trying to reference in constructor above. In other words, constructor should treat it as null.
}
```

Obviously, my `obj` is getting created with `obj.Price` being null.

Is there a way to:

**1) Modifying getter/setter for `Price` to not have it has property for `obj` if its not coming in from serializedJson?**

**2) Remove the property "Price" from object because its null?**

Comment: 1st: Price IMHO shouldn't be a string. Anyway you can't remove the property of an object, but you could define it in a way you know it's not valid, eg (only an example) `_price = somePrice ?? "0"; `. Last thought: do you want to remove the property when serializing your class?

Comment: Well with regards to the second question, C# is statically typed so you certainly can't remove any properties from a class dynamically.

Comment: if the data is null value, then you do nothing to update the value of the data you are trying to replace you can't remove the property. You can check the property for null value and do nothing to update the data.

Comment: why do you use a string for 'price', which is clearly a number? use nullable float instead.

Comment: @FalcoGer: Using `float` for currency is a very bad idea. It's usually important to be able to represent monetary values precisely - which is the principal use case for `decimal`. (Indeed, it may well be that `string` was being used to avoid the issues of using `float` for prices...)

Comment: @JonSkeet in any case, when you need the string representation, you use the string at that point. price is not a string.

Comment: @FalcoGer: Sure, I suspect that using a string is a bad idea - but so is using a float, that's my point. (I'd say that using float is possibly *worse* than string, as it's more likely to lose information.)

Comment: string Price is being used here just as an example. Sorry I should have been more clear about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove a property of an object dynamically, but you can use the getter to give the null value and return whatever you need, for example:

```
get
{
    return _price ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have value for Price field in deserialize object, then you must create `public string Price { get; set; }` and add suitable attribute, else if Price is depend on deserialized object then:

```
someclass(serializedJson)
{
    JavascriptSerializer js = new JavascriptSerializer();
    var newObj = (someClass)(js.deserialize(serializedJson, typeof(serializedJson)));
    Price = // ... some code
}
pblic string Price { get; }
```